# Are there other mutants with secondary powers?

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men, powers

In the *X-Men* films (and assumingly comics), we see characters obtain secondary powers unrelated to their primary mutation. The most obvious example is Kitty Pryde later developing an ability to send others' consciousness back in time after only having the power to phase through objects.

What other mutants have had secondary powers distinct from their primary powers develop later in life?

Comment: Are you asking about the comics or the movies or both? Kitty does not have the secondary mutation in the comics.

Answer (score 4):

Phenomenon is known as Secondary mutation. This is a phenomenon which among mutants that seems inexplicable, with many previously established mutant characters suddenly developing new or vastly expanded powers

Some of the known mutants having secondary mutation are:

> Gambit (Remy Lebeau): Gambit is able to psionically suggest things to
>   people using his hypnotic charm. It allows him to exert a subtle
>   influence over sentient beings, leading them to believe what he says
>   and agree with his suggestions.
>
> Polaris (Lorna Dane): after having her mutant powers leeched by her
>   supposed-sister, Zaladane, Lorna developed the first recorded case.
>   Her body mass had increased, along with her strength and resistance to
>   injury.
>
> Emma Frost: Emma's secondary mutation activated in the midst of the
>   bombing of Genosha by Cassandra Nova's wild Mega-Sentinels. She
>   transformed into an indestructible organic diamond form that saved her
>   life, but negates her telepathy so she cannot use both powers at once

There are many more. Follow [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_mutation) to find more details